# Angular 2, change another component's view from unrelated component

Tags: angular, components

I'm able to change the value of a component's variable from another component as `console.log()` shows in this example.

My problem is that second component's view does not refresh despite the variable change.

Example:

**first.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {SecondComponent} from './second.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'first',
    template: `
        <h2>First component</h2>
        <button (click)="changeOutside()">Change</button>
    `,
    providers: [SecondComponent]
})
export class FirstComponent {
    constructor(private otherComponent: SecondComponent) {}
    changeOutside() {
        this.otherComponent.change();
    }
}
```

**second.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'second',
    template: `
        <h2>Second component</h2>
        <div>Pet: {{animal}}</div>
        <button (click)="change()">Change</button>
    `
})
export class SecondComponent {
    animal: string = 'Dog';
    change() {
        this.animal = 'Cat';
        console.log(this.animal);
    }
}
```

Both components are totally **unrelated** from different branches of the DOM tree.

I've also tried with the first component emitting an event and the second component subscribing to it with the same result, the variable changes but view does not update.

---

After [Günter's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39722966/5626903) (thanks), I've tried with the next solution with no success. Even the `console.log` is not working.

**first.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {UpdateService} from './update.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'first',
    template: `
        <h2>First component</h2>
        <button (click)="changeOutside()">Change</button>
    `
})
export class FirstComponent {
    constructor(private updateService: UpdateService) {}
    changeOutside() {
        this.updateService.changeAnimal('Cat');
    }
}
```

**update.service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class UpdateService {
    // Observable string sources
    private newAnimalSource = new Subject<string>();
    // Observable string streams
    newAnimal$ = this.newAnimalSource.asObservable();

    changeAnimal(animal: string) {
        this.newAnimalSource.next(animal);
    }
}
```

**second.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {UpdateService} from './update.service';
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Component({
    selector: 'second',
    template: `
        <h2>Second component</h2>
        <div>Pet: {{animal}}</div>
        <button (click)="change()">Change</button>
    `
})
export class SecondComponent {
    animal: string = 'Dog';
    subscription: Subscription;
    constructor(private updateService: UpdateService) {
        this.subscription = updateService.newAnimal$.subscribe(
            animal => {
                console.log(animal);
                this.animal = animal;
        });
    }
    change() {
        this.animal = 'Cat';
    }
}
```

---

### Solved

Finally, the solution proposed by **Günter** worked after adding `UpdateService` as a `provider` in the `@NgModule` of `app.module.ts`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**update**

I'm pretty sure the cause of your problem is that you expect

```
constructor(private otherComponent: SecondComponent) {}
```

to do something that it actually doesn't do at all.

With this constructor you get a `SecondComponent` instance injected that is not related to the component shown in your page. This is why your view isn't updated. You didn't update the visible component but an entirely unrelated class.

You need to use a different strategy to get a reference to the other component.

The best way is to **not** get a reference to the component at all but instead inject a shared service to both and communicate using observables.

For more details refer [this official angular 2 cookbook](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service)

**original**

If both components are "totally unrelated", I assume this means they are from individually bootstrapped module and therefore inside different Angular2 applications on the same page.

In this case these components run in different zones and the `click` event will only cause change detection in the calling component but not in the callee component.

You need to invoke change detection explicitly in the callee to get the view updated. For example like

```
import {Component, ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'second',
    template: `
        <h2>Second component</h2>
        <div>Pet: {{animal}}</div>
        <button (click)="change()">Change</button>
    `
})
export class SecondComponent {
    constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef){}

    animal: string = 'Dog';
    change() {
        this.animal = 'Cat';
        console.log(this.animal);
        this.cdRef.detectChanges();
    }
}
```

or

```
import {Component, NgZone} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'second',
    template: `
        <h2>Second component</h2>
        <div>Pet: {{animal}}</div>
        <button (click)="change()">Change</button>
    `
})
export class SecondComponent {
    constructor(private zone:NgZone){}

    animal: string = 'Dog';
    change() {
        this.zone.run(() => {
          this.animal = 'Cat';
          console.log(this.animal);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I have not explained myself well. With _totally unrelated_ I tried to reflect that they aren't parent or child of each other. Anyway, I will try your solution. Thanks.

Comment: My solution is only applicable if they are in different Angular2 applications.

Comment: `UpdateService` should be added to providers of an `@NgModule(...)` decorator. In your case if you add it to both components, both components get a different instance. If one of the components is a parent of the other, you can also provide it at the parent **only** or another component that is a common parent (ancestor) of both.

Comment: **That was it!**, added `UpateService` as provider for `@NgModule` in `app.module.ts` and it works. Thank you very much for your accurate and quick answers.

Answer (score 1):

### Solved

As I edited in the question, the solution proposed by **Günter**, which is the second series of files, worked after adding `UpdateService` as a `provider` in the `@NgModule` of `app.module.ts`